# Move all images whose names appear in a txt file to a new folder using the windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, script

I have a text file which contains the filenames of all JPEG files in a folder.

I use something like this to populate the text file.

```
dir /s /b /a-d c:\temp\*jpg > c:\temp\Images.txt
```

Example:

```
Current Folder = C:\temp  Destination Folder = C:\newHome
```

Text file contents (a.k.a List):

```
hello.jpg
world.jpg
summer.jpg
```

I am trying use the text file as a list

Then move all the JPEG files on that list from their Current folder to the Destination folder

I know there is a similar question somewhere on here but that is for linux only.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) - Loop command: against a set of files - conditionally perform a command against each item.

Comment: if you capture the full path (instead of using the brief flag), then you can brute force it by search and replace `c:\\ ` with `move "c:\\ ` and replace `.jpg` with `.jpg" "c:\\destination\\"`